# react-native webview doesn't support some URL schemes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

**react**: 16.9.0
**react-native**: 0.61.5,

**ISSUE:**
I am using `react-native-community/react-native-webview`, to render a web view in my application. My URL scheme looks something like **intent://cdn.glitch.com/** (which is basically a `WebAR`, that basically opens a 3D model in the space around with help of camera). It throws an error saying ERROR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

**What I have tried till now:**

- Downgraded react-native version to 0.59.0 before WebView module was extracted to react-native-community package and use the WebView component that ships in with 0.59.0. The URL scheme works perfectly in this case, and the WebAR works seamlessly.
- Downgrade the `react-native-webview` package. Things didn't work in this case.

**CONCLUSION:**
The WebView component that comes up with to react-native 0.59.0 below works fine with the URL schemes, however the `react-native-webview` package doesn't.

**Help Needed:**

- Is there any way to support such URL schemes?
- Is there any way to include, the extracted WebView module in the latest version of react-native?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issues by making changes to the RNCWebViewManager.java file. Things now works as expected, however support for IOS is yet to be added.

The pull request for the feature could be found
[here.](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/1136)